# Subscribe via json-rpc has no response

Tags: polkadot-js, json-rpc

I don't get any response from `json-rpc` subscription.

It seems I need a `type` paramater, but the `provider.subscribe()` method does not document the `type` parameter. (I checked the [js, java and python code](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/d64a1fcfd3bcbe6fba589937bbba13d928b2007b/packages/rpc-provider/src/ws/index.ts#L377), can't find any explanation of this param).

```js
const { WsProvider } = require('@polkadot/api');

(async () => {

  const provider = new WsProvider('wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io');
  var count = 0

  const type = '' // @param string <==== what should this be?
  const method = 'chain_subscribeAllHeads'
  // const method = 'subscribeAllHeads' // => method not found
  // const method = 'state_subscribeRuntimeVersion'
  const params = []

  const unsub = await provider.subscribe(type, method, params, (err, response) => {
    count++
    console.log(err, response)
    if(count > 2) {
      unsub()
      process.exit(0)
    }
  })
})()
```